# Productive cooperation or "A" productive cooperation

Tags: grammar

I wrote in an email the next sentence:

"I believe we could have a productive cooperation."

I'm using Grammarly and it suggested removing the **a** and change the sentence to: I believe we could have productive cooperation.

I feel like it's a mistake but I can't figure out why Grammarly would think that's a mistake (that's a very simple, straightforward sentence, with no special ambiguity).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What about cooperate productively?

Comment: @Peter - That's an option. But I was wondering why the "a" is considered wrong, even for curiosity's sake.

Comment: The algorithm regards cooperation as an uncountable noun, so it suggests removing "a" which would treat it as countable. Thankfully the final decision is made by the human at the keyboard.

Comment: Either would do with different meanings; it's the difference between "a" identifying a specific instance, and the general case. Grammarly tries to guess which is more common or which you mean, probably based on some kind of statistical evidence about how "cooperation" is normally used.

Comment: 'A' is arguably not wrong here. But @Peter's suggestion is far better than either. Why choose between a suspect hobby-horse and a suspect old bike when you're being offered a warrantied Ferrari?